# Moved from Windows 32 Bit to Linux 64 Bit, base_convert() issues

Tags: php, centos, lamp

I was working on Windows 64 Bit with 32 Bit php on it. Using base_convert After i have moved to Centos 64 Bit with 64 Bit php returns different results. For example:

```
<?php
    $input = 'f00706ff';
    $result  = (int)base_convert($input,16,10);
    echo $result;
?>
```

On Win64 PHP32     -> 2147483647;

On CentOS64 PHP64  -> 4026992383;

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
<?php
    $input = 'f00706ff';
    $result  = (int)base_convert($input,16,10);
    if($result > 2147483647) $result = 2147483647;
    echo $result;
?>
```

Where 2147483647 = PHP_INT_MAX in 32 BIT

Answer (score 1):

Your Windows value was wrong because your hex value was outside of the range of 32bit integers (2147483647 is the maximum in base 10 for signed integers) and you were running PHP's 32 bit version. The Linux result is correct :)

Also note that if you'd like to perform the operation properly on Windows, you can use the GNU Multiple Precision library like so: `$result = gmp_strval( gmp_init('f00706ff', 16), 10 );` though working with integers of the size you are on a 32-bit platform in PHP seems like it'd be unplesant to say the least.

Comment: Is there a way i can make my linux behave like windows now?

Comment: Not other than running a 32-bit version of PHP. (Which won't work very well.)

Comment: To ensure urls not give 404 on new server . :)